# VBA: dynamically manage excel tables

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have the following table,
[image]

how can I create a Macro that if I click on a right button/link "Remove" removes the line in the table and if I click add it adds an empty line at the end of the table?

Comment: easiest way to start would be to record a macro performing those actions.

Answer (score 0):

Record a macro and do it manually one time.

After it you can check the generated code for the macro, so you can get an idea how to do it with VBA. 
That will be better to give you a snippet, since you will learn more and your problem is not a huge one.